# Computer hangs at "Verifying DMI pool data" after adding second RAM module

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I have a machine that currently has one 2GB stick of DDR2 667 MHz RAM. I'm trying to upgrade to 4GB by adding a second 2GB DDR2 667 MHz stick.

When I install the second stick of RAM the computer gets to the first boot stage then hangs at the message:

> Verifying DMI pool data........... Success.

I have tried both sticks of RAM in a different machine and it booted without any problems. What can I do to fix this?

I have a Foxconn 945GC7MC-KRS2H motherboard.

Comment: What happens when you boot the machine with *only* the new stick of RAM installed?

Comment: The same thing happens just gets to the same point and hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Foxconn's [specifications for your motherboard](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=Motherboard&U=en-us0000305), it only supports a maximum of 2 GB of RAM:

> Dual channel DDR2 400/533 x 2 DIMMs, **Max 2GB**

Comment: Okay Thanks, I ran a crucial scan which said it supported up to 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Although rare, I have encountered instances where Crucial.com is incorrect. However, this has me thinking. Do you by chance have an add-on video card? If so, try your 2nd stick of RAM *without* the video card installed (use the on-board graphics temporarily).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, however I don't have an add-on video card all I have is the on-board graphics.